# Is there a pthread_once equivalent in Java?

Tags: java, concurrency

In C/C++ world, it is very easy make a routine executed just once by using pthread_once. In Java, I generally use static atomic variables to do the explicit check if the routine was run already. But that looks ugly and hence wondering if there is something like pthrea_once in Java.

Comment: Java guarantees each class will be initialised once when it is first needed, which gives you all you need for once only initialisation.

Comment: I voted for your comment, but you should write an answer, because when you read pthread_once man (http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_once ), the behaviour explained is close to how with static initializers work.

Answer (score 1):

Since you refer to “static atomic variables” you seem to talk about `static` resources which do not need special actions if you initialize them within the class initializer itself:

```
class Foo {
  static ResourceType X = createResource();
}
```

Here, `createResource()` will be executed exactly once in a thread-safe manner on the first use of `Foo`, e.g. when `Foo.X` is accessed the first time. Threads accessing `X` while the class initialization is in progress are forced to wait, but subsequent access will be performed without any synchronization overhead. Typically, but not necessarily, the variable will be declared `final` as well.

If you have multiple resources whose creation should be deferred independently, the owner class might use inner classes, each of them holding one resource.

If your question is about an action which should be executed exactly once without returning a value, the static initialization can be used as well. You only have to add a member you can access to trigger the class initialization, e.g.:

```
class Foo {
  static { performAction(); }
  static void performActionOnce() {}
}
```

Here, calling `Foo.performActionOnce()` will cause `performAction()` to be executed the first time while all other subsequent invocations do nothing. You can also rely on that on returning from `performActionOnce()` the action within `performAction()` has been completed, even when there is contention on the first invocation.

---

This is different from any atomic variable approach as atomic variables do not provide a sufficient waiting capability for the case that the first invocation is contended. If you combine the atomic variable with a waiting queue, you end up what `Lock` (or any other [AQS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.html) based concurrency tool) provides. For instance variables where the static initialization does not work, there is no simple workaround (besides thinking about whether initialization really has to be lazy).